# WiX ingores a running program when running uninstall for non-default path

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.11

WiX installer uses regular dialogs for specifying the target path:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
```

When the user just clicks through the installation wizard the default path is used. The user then runs the program (SomeExecutable.exe) and leaves it running. He then goes to list of programs and asks Windows to uninstall the program. The wizard properly displays a message saying that SomeExecutable.exe is running, so a restart would be needed. That's the expected behavior.

However if the user changes the target to something like `c:\UserSpecificedFolder` then installation works just fine but when an uninstall is attempted while SomeExecutable.exe is running then unistall finishes without any messages and files are not removed. The program continues running. That's not the expected behavior.

It looks like some extra step is needed to inform the installer that install path was changed and so it should treat the new path as install path when uninstall is being run.

Why would it not work?

Answer (score 0):

What does the Windows Installer uninstall log say?  I'm not completely convinced this is a problem even though it seems obvious.   WiX only creates MSI databases.  It doesn't do the uninstall, MSI does.  MSI only prompts file in use / reboot interactions when it isn't able to do an operation.  If there is no file lock it may be completely normal to not see it.

My follow up question would be is the file uninstalled at the end without rebooting?